# Prolog error in sample code

Tags: prolog

I was reading a book about prolog and tried pasting their sample code to see how it would work and I get errors. What's wrong with this code.

```
   path(X,Y)← 
    path(X,Y,[X]).


  path(X,X,Visited).
  path(X,Z,Visited)←
     edge(X,Y),
     not member(Y,Visited),
     path(Y,Z,[Y|Visited]). 

 member(X,[X|Y]). 
 member(X,[Y|Z])← 
    member(X,Z)
```

Comment: What prolog interpreter are you using? What errors are you getting? *I just keep getting errors* is a bit difficult to help with. What are you typing in for `←`? Prolog interpreters don't use that. Those are used in books. In the interpreter you need `:-`. Check the online documentation for the particular Prolog implementation you are using.

Comment: iirc, the art of prolog used such notation

Comment: @CapelliC and TAOP is a book right? I did say that the notation is used in books. :) You just can't copy/paste it into a Prolog REPL and expect to use it was my point.

Comment: @lurker: copy/paste from PDF should be feasible, as long as it is text, not bitmaps. Anyway, *understanding* the code is well beyond copy/paste, for sure. I was only showcasing the flexibility of Prolog source, specially now that we have UTF8 available. Indeed, I don't even care what code `←` could be....

Comment: @CapelliC of course it's feasible. It all depends upon what character set was used. I think showing how the special character could indeed be made usable is cool. I just don't think it answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

in SWI-Prolog, the following declarations make your code compilable

```
:- op(1200, xfx, ←).
:- op(900, fy, not).

:- multifile term_expansion/2.
term_expansion((H←B), (H:-B)).
term_expansion((not B), (\+ B)).

path(X,Y)←
    path(X,Y,[X]).

path(X,X,Visited).
path(X,Z,Visited)←
     edge(X,Y),
     not member(Y,Visited),
     path(Y,Z,[Y|Visited]). 

member(X,[X|Y]). 
member(X,[Y|Z])← 
    member(X,Z).
```

there are some warnings about singletons, and you're missing the final dot... I provided it